# How to write to same excel file after the operation with sheet name

Tags: pandas

I have excel file name 'excel.xlsx'. it is having `10` sheets with different name. `I am  able to save but all other sheets are missing`

- After the Operation I need to save the sheet on the same excel starting from `5th` row and `5th` column
- The new sheet name is `'Final'`
- My dataframe name is df

  ```
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Final', startrow=5,startcol=5,index=False)
  writer.save()
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to add a `writer.save()` before your df.to_excel(...)?

Comment: Nothing is printing

Answer (score 0):

Will be easier - Try using **openpyxl** engine.

Prerequisite: **openpyxl** - Install it with command -

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Variables used:

1. sh_nm= Sheet Name you want to append in the workbook.
2. filename= Workbook name.
3. df=Dataframe for your new sheet.

> Note: Exceptions not handled .

---

**Code**:

---

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# !pip install openpyxl
def sheet_collate(filename,_df,sh_nm):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
        _df.to_excel(writer,sh_nm, startrow=5,startcol=5,index=False)
        writer.save()
    return "Workbook Edited.."

filename='excel.xlsx'
sh_nm='Final'
sheet_collate(filename,df,sh_nm)
```

Comment: what is book? is it a method

Comment: Yes.
I am really sorry.